Not able to see toggle button to switch to live mode
I am creating android app using firebase and incorporated Facebook Login, I completed all the steps to setup app but couldn't find toggle button to make it live in Facebook dashboard.
Below is the image of my app dashboard, where I couldn't see toggle button.
Facebook Dashboard Screenshot
I tried exploring all options in dashboard to see if it's present inside them but it wasn't there.
